# WordPress elementor project

Tags: javascript, wordpress, scroll, elementor, snappy

I'm working on elementor project.

In which I want the page scroll behavior to be snappy and horizontal.
One full page at a time.

I managed to make the horizontal feature, but how I can make it snappy.

Here is my code:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    main {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      display: flex;
    }

    section {
      min-width: 100vw!important;
      min-height: 100vh!important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.innerWidth > 1025) {
       const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

        scrollContainer.addEventListener("wheel", (evt) => {
            evt.preventDefault();
            scrollContainer.scrollLeft += evt.deltaY;
        });
    } else {

}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does "snappy" mean?

Comment: Hello, I mean with one mouse wheel scroll to change the entire page.
Something like this https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/